# How do I update blog article in django using model forms?

Tags: python, django, forms, model, modelform

I am creating a blog using django. I am using model Forms for input.I want to edit an existing blog post, but I can't get this to work.

**models.py**

```
class tags(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    post = HTMLField()
    editor = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(tags,blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    article_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='articles/', blank=True)
    photo_credits = models.CharField(max_length=60,default='unsplash.com')
```

**Forms.py**

```
class UpdateArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Article
    fields = ['title','article_image','post','tags','photo_credits']
```

**Views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
    def update_article(request,id):
    instance = Article.objects.get(id = id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = UpdateArticleForm(instance=instance)
    return render(request,'article/update.html',{'form':form})
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^article/update/$',views.update_article,name='update_article'),
```

I get a 404 error.and if I replace the url with the below I get a `Reverse for 'update_article' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['article/update/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']`

```
    url(r'^article/update/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$',views.update_article,name='update_article'),
```

How can I get this to work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your views and url configurations are correct, errors probably reside in your templates. Try to find `{% url "update_article" %}` in your template and replace with
`{% url "update_article" <article_id> %}`

Comment: @GeoffreyMungai replace `<article_id>` with real `article_id` you would like to edit, that's why I use `< >` in first place. For instance,  if you rendered article using variables `article`, then use {% url "update_article" article.id %} for updating

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have 'tags' field in the form, but in model you name it 'tag'.

Comment: i have the tags model in my models.py. I have edited to show it